# yii1.1: $model->save() failed, but $model->getErrors() return empty array

Tags: yii

I'm using YII1.1.16, I have some code like this:

```
public function actionAdd()
{
    $article = new Article;
    $article->type = $this->type;

    if (isset($_POST['article'])) {
        $article->attributes = $_POST['article'];
        if ($article->save()) {
            $this->success('saved');
        } else {
            var_dump($article->getErrors());
        }
    }

    $this->render('add');
}
```

but, now the `save()` failed, but `getErrors()` return empty array(), so how can I know why it failed when saving the record?

Comment: Did you use `beforeSave()` ? Does it return `parent::beforeSave()` ?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti I found why. your thinking it's right, althought the problem is my `beforeValidate()` method is not returning `parent::beforeValidate()`. thank you!